# Automatically getting google search results from extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-search, google-search-api, postman

This might have been asked before in different forms.

My use case is that i'm trying to generate http request from a chrome/firefox extension to a google search results page (by just the url of a search). Tried postman rest client for chrome, however google home page pops up.
Thinking if there is something google dynamically doing to prevent seeing the results in the returned page? Isn't that request just like the client machine's request? I am able to paste the url in a different browser and it works.
Any thoughts on this and/or know someone who's already done this?

Other solutions are to get a web service that has a web scraper like scrapy (python) or some java based and crawls with multiple proxy nodes there to get results. However didn't want to go that route, unless its the only one.

NPAPI for chrome: seems unsafe

During this it hit me, how are all the new search engines able to produce the same if not better results than google - and google has been around way longer tweaking its algorithms optimally and crawling the web. The new algorithms could not compete with the sophistication google might have achieved by now, even if the fundamental was the same. Blekko, Duckduckgo, bing and many more - all seem to produce pretty similar results as google as well. Aren't they just merely calling google from their numerous proxy nodes to simulate user behavior? Or have crawled google enough to already build their results.

Any help or thoughts would be great.

Comment: What is it you're asking exactly? And yes, Google will do everything in its power to deny automated queries.

Comment: In a chrome or firefox extension - I want to get google search results. One way was to construct the query ex == https://www.google.com/...q=queryword1+queryword2+queryword3... (after the q) == which if use a rest client like postman (an existing chrome extension) it gives me the google home page instead. What would I have to do to search google automatically from a chrome or firefox extension. They use javascript. Do you know if I need to change headers, or pass cookies etc

Comment: Basically, you need to pay. A lot. https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview If you don't use this API, you are breaking Google's terms of service and it will block your queries.

Comment: or i can try to automate my browser. we are still able to search google through our browser - can i just depict that in some way? after all it is my computer..

Comment: You are allowed to open a tab with the search; you are not allowed to collect the results programmatically. If you do try it and circumvent that, you will greatly inconvenience the user as ALL searches from this IP (or even subnet) may have bot checks enabled (CAPTCHA is not fun)

Comment: have never seen capcha on google search when searching from browser. i am not worried about volume as i won't have much. just need to run a google search in the background, as im just trying to make a custom front end for the results. so just need to make it look like it's coming from the browser. don't know if it's possible to open a background tab in chrome or firefox rather than an actual tab. and then just get the html into an html parser and get the results along with their links. do you think that would work?